# clearInterval and set it again after x seconds

Tags: javascript

I want to do simple interval with with `if`, It is checking a variable's value and doing a function `again()`.

`again` function contains `clearInterval`, `i++` and `setTimeout` to call interval `again` after **`x`** seconds

```
    var speed = 1000;
    var wait = 0;
    var i = 0;

    function init() {
        setInterval(function() {
            if (i >= 6) i = 0;
            if (i == 4) {
                wait = 5000;
                again(wait);
            } else {
                document.body.innerHTML = i;
                i++;
            }
        }, speed);
    }

    function again(time) {
        clearInterval(init());
        i++;
        setTimeout(function() {
            setInterval(init(), speed);
        }, time);
    }
    init();
```

I expect output like this:

```
1, 2, 3, Waiting x sec's , 5, 1, 2, ...
```

but code is doing some thing crazy, Its going faster and faster. I don't know why.

Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WxWzRz?editors=0010) with example (can crash your browser!)

Can you fix it and explain? Thanks

Comment: `clearInterval(init());` doesn't clear the interval. In fact, it sets up _a new one_.

Comment: option with var x = setInterval(function() {}, and then clearInterval(x); still not works

Comment: `setInterval` returns an ID. Give `clearInterval` that ID to stop the loop. Ex: `var id = setInterval(init, time); clearInterval(id)`.

Comment: `setInterval(init(), speed);` will also be a problem - you want to pass the function, not invoke it: `setInterval(init, speed);`

Comment: And calling `init` from `setInterval`, which then calls `setInterval`... Are you sure that's what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not clearing interval but use function inside clearInterval method. Method **init** which is used has no return statement so clearInterval gets undefined in attribute, so it is not clearing nothing.

Fixed code:

```
var speed = 1000;
var wait = 0;
var i = 0;
var interval=null;

function init() {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (i >= 6) i = 0;
        if (i == 4) {
            wait = 5000;
            again(wait);
        } else {
            document.body.innerHTML = i;
            i++;
        }
    }, speed);
}

function again(time) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    i++;
    setTimeout(function() {

    init()

    }, time);
}

init();
```

Function **setInterval** returns interval id and function **clearInterval** in attribute should get id of interval which we want to stop, so I created interval variable to save id. I am using this variable in clearInterval.

Answer (score 0):

This is a small example how changing the delay of a `setInterval` call.

```
(function iife() {
    var timer = null,
        counter = 0;

  function task() {
    counter += 1;
    console.log(counter);
    // condition: every four reps
    if (counter % 4 === 0) {
      console.log("changed speed to 4 seconds");
      return start(4000);
    }
    // condition: every seven reps
    if (counter % 7 === 0) {
      console.log("changed speed to 2 seconds");
      return start(2000);
    }
  }

  function start(delay) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    console.log("runs every " + delay + " miliseconds");
    timer = setInterval(task, delay);
  }

  start(1000);

}());
```